# Objects Breaking Apart When Rigged

Tags: modeling, rigging, armature

I am trying to rig a conveyor belt in Blender for importing into a game engine. For this, I am using the tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O8qZN3cjX4c) as a guideline, as I am new to rigging.

The basic idea of the method is as follows:

1. Take a mesh and repeat it using an array modifier. Then, use a curve modifier to map it to a Bezier Circle.
2. Generate bones equidistantly for each track segment, driven by the rotation of an empty sphere object for controlling the rotation.
3. Generate a separate, combined armature of all reference bones. Then, apply a Copy Transform and Copy Rotation bone constraint for each bone of the main armature to the original bones.
4. Parent the armature to the mesh, which enables the track to rotate around using the control sphere.
5. Modify the Bezier Circle to obtain the desired loop shape.

After much trial and error, I got this to work nicely for the primary track segments. However, parts of the track segment modelled separately and joined to the mesh do not follow the track and appear to be precessing around the primary path for some reason.

Can someone please explain why this is happening and how I can resolve the issue?

I have included the model file at the bottom of the post and images illustrating the problem.

**Edit Mode Image of the Track, Following The Circle**
[image: Edit Mode Image of the Track, Following The Circle]

**Rigged Model, Where Separate Pieces Are Not Following The Modifier**

[image: Rigged Model, Where Separate Pieces Are Not Following The Modifier]

**Example Project File**

[image]